# How can I tell if a hadoop namenode has already been formatted?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When configuring my hadoop namenode for the first time, I know I need to run

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

but running this a second time, after loading data into HDFS, will wipe out everything and reformat. Is there an easy way to tell if a namenode has already been formatted?

Answer (score 4):

Well you can check this file
store1/name/current/VERSION

If it exist then it is already formatted.

PS: You do format only once in life in production system. Its better to do in the installation process or manually in emergency restoration time.

Comment: Thejaswi, thanks for this -- I'm working on a configure script that takes care of everything, and want to be able to run configure multiple times without screwing up HDFS. Configure lifts up the three new configuration files, and makes sure everything is set up properly. I ended up just echoing `N` when I did the call to format, as this tells the node NOT to reformat HDFS.

Comment: Where exactly to look for that file?